# Dagger 2, Gradle Plugins and Jack - Guidance Required

Tags: java, android, java-8, android-gradle-plugin, dagger-2

I'm using Dagger 2 (first time user of the DI library) with Android Studio (AS 2.1.2 - SDK 24), and obviously my first thought is "What dependencies do I need in order to use it?"

Having looked at examples I can see that you need in the top level `build.gradle` file you need a annotation processor plugin:

```
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
```

Now the dependencies in the `Module` level `build.gradle` apply the apt plugin for the `Module` so I end up with something like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

// other generic settings - android / buildTypes etc.

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    .
    .
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.6'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.6'
    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
}
```

**PROBLEM**

I have been using, for sometime, the Jack Tool Chain and Java 8 in my projects and found out the above configuration is incompatible with Jack.

Having researched what I needed in order for Jack and Dagger 2 to cooperate I changed the following:

**gradle-wrapper.properties :**

Changed to :

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip`

**build.gradle** (Top Level)

Changed to:

```
classpath 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0' // added after getting NoSuchMethod Error - it solved the issue
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha7'
```

**build.gradle** (Module Level)

Changed to:

```
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.6'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.6'
```

With these changes I was able to use the Jack Tool Chain, and build a small project.  However without changing any code I started having trouble with my Component creation - in a simple line of code : `testComponent = DaggerTestComponent.builder().build();` the word `DaggerTestComponent` became red (obviously the Dagger 2 library wasn't working as it should).  I managed to resolve the error by a good old invalidate caches, clean and rebuild. However I have been plagued with random errors each time I try and build the small test project - I have managed a couple times to run the app (and it works as expected), but obviously it is quite temperamental.

**QUESTION**

So the question, and I apologise for it taking this long, but thought that all of the above was relevant,

**Is there a more 'Stable' setup than what I'm using at the moment? Has anyone else encountered these problems?**

Obviously I don't have to use the Jack tool chain and Java 8, but I'd rather not compromise if I don't have to!

Comment: any updates on this one? it is still happening

Comment: @GabbarSingh Yes, still have to rebuild every time with the jack toolchain when i change a line of code. I reverted back to using retrolambda instead, i have no problems, plus build times are dramatically quicker not using jack toolchain